# How do I close a question on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

OK, I asked a question, and it gets answered. I don't want to bother anyone anymore, so I want to mark my question as answered and consequently closed. How do I do that?

Comment: This belongs on META and not AU plus it is covered in the FAQ here: http://askubuntu.com/faq#close  " Questions that are not a good fit for this site may be voted closed by experienced community members. Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting. See How to Ask for guidance on editing your question to improve it. ". In short: you do not close it since 'solved' in itself is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: You should answer your own question on how you fixed your problem.  That way it can help future visitors that got the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get answer from any of the proposed answer, you can check the grey tick mark on the left side of the answer. In this way, It will be marked as having an accepted answer.

If you don't get the answer from any of the proposed answer, but by other way *(such as in Ubuntu forums, Linux forums or other stack Exchange site or by your own research )* then you should write the answer, and accept it. This way, the future visitor will be benefited from your answer. *Note that, you can accept your own answer after two days of submitting question*.

And for the *consequently closed* feature, As far As I know, this is not possible. The question will be open for any future answers. Even, later answers can get more upvotes than the original accepted answer. The question is only closed if they do not comply with Ask Ubuntu policy as the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#close) indicates.

Comment: Well, it's not really true that only questions that don't comply with a the policy are closed. Duplicate questions are closed, and unless someone is *deliberately* posting a question they are *sure* is a duplicate, they're not doing anything wrong. Furthermore, a question could *become* too localized after being posted--for example, the problem could mysteriously go away, with the OP unable to articulate any explanation or course of action that ameliorated it.

Comment: thanks everybody, got it now.

Comment: But what if it is not possible to test any following answer? For example, i made a question when I was working on a company, and right now i´m not working on it anymore, so I don´t have access to the context of the problem anymore. So, any answer on the future will not be useful anymore, because I don´t have that problem anymore, and I can´t test the solutions... (my problem was something about the proxy setting of my company)